# Whats the difference between couchbase capella vs couchbase server?

Tags: couchbase

I have a question and want to ask you:

Whats the difference between couchbase capella vs couchbase server ?

And what would you recommend to use ?

Do I have the same benefits on the capella as the server ?

thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic (see: [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), or question is too broad, and answered here: [Search Engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=couchbase+capella+vs+couchbase+server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to think about it: Couchbase Capella is a managed database-as-a-service, hosted version of Couchbase Server. Couchbase manages the infrastructure, the software, upgrades, patches, and so on. You get access to it via a control plane.

Couchbase Server is the host-it-yourself, downloadable version. It can be deployed pretty much anywhere, but you will have to manage the upgrades, patches, infrastructure, and so on.

That being said, there are differences between them, and that's likely to continue. For instance, Capella also has "App Services" available as part of the platform. This is roughly equivalent to Couchbase Sync Gateway, which would be yet another downloadable install for you to manage.

But I think the more important question, and the one probably not great for Stack Overflow, is "And what would you recommend to use?"

Short answer: if you have the time, expertise, resources, and experience in hosting your own Couchbase cluster, and want maximum control, you might be good with Server. Otherwise, I'd say Capella.